# Warning for `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. won't go away even with updating the code to new command syntax

Tags: github, github-actions, deprecation-warning

I am trying to update the 'set-output' syntax in my GitHub workflow, but nothing that I have done has cleared the warning. I followed the guide GitHub gave, but am I missing something, or is the $() miss placed?

It currently uses `actions/checkout@v3`, which I think also impacts it.

```
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      branch: ${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}
      channel: ${{ steps.extract_channel.outputs.channel }}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # In this step, this action saves a list of existing images,
      # the cache is created without them in the post run.
      # It also restores the cache if it exists.
    - name: Install Octopus CLI 
      uses: OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action@v3
    - name: Extract branch name
      shell: bash
      id: extract_branch
      run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
      # run: echo "branch=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Determine Octopus Deployment Channel
      shell: bash
      id: extract_channel
      run: |
          BRANCH="${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}"
          CHANNEL="Features"
            if [[ "$BRANCH" == "main" ]] || [[ "$BRANCH" == "release/*" ]]; then
              CHANNEL="default"
            fi
            
            echo "##[set-output name=channel;]$(echo $CHANNEL)"
        # echo "channel=$(echo $CHANNEL)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

[annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8iSP.png) ,
[output code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSfae.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the logs, the warning should be right in the section of the action or script causing the warning to be issued:

[image: The warning is highlighted in the actual logs]

The updated script still has the old syntax, with the new syntax commented out:

```
echo "##[set-output name=channel;]$(echo $CHANNEL)"
# echo "channel=$(echo $CHANNEL)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Update that to:

```
echo "channel=$(echo $CHANNEL)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Updated the workflow to the one below and the warnings are gone:

```
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # In this step, this action saves a list of existing images,
      # the cache is created without them in the post run.
      # It also restores the cache if it exists.
    - name: Install Octopus CLI 
      uses: OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action@v3
    - name: Extract branch name
      shell: bash
      id: extract_branch
      run: echo "branch=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Determine Octopus Deployment Channel
      shell: bash
      id: extract_channel
      run: |
          BRANCH="${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}"
          CHANNEL="Features"
            if [[ "$BRANCH" == "main" ]] || [[ "$BRANCH" == "release/*" ]]; then
              CHANNEL="default"
            fi
            
            echo "channel=$(echo $CHANNEL)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

If this isn't the complete workflow, then some other task must be logging these warnings.

Try downloading the full log archive to find the exact location the warning is logged:

[image]

Based on the logs you attached, the [EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action](https://github.com/EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action) is way behind. Your workflow uses 1.31, while 2.6.1 is out already. [1.31 still logs to the output](https://github.com/EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action/blob/v1.31/python/publish/github_action.py#L21).

To make it easier to stay up to date, enable Dependabot-version-updates for GitHub Actions. Add `.github/dependabot.yml` to your repo:

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/" # Location of package manifests
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

And enable version updates in your repo settings:

[image]

That way GitHub will automatically tell you what actions are falling behind.

Comment: The warning doesn't show up like that, it is just shown in the annotations

Comment: added it to the questions

Comment: Added the log with the error up top

Comment: @SabrinaGrosse did you see the update I made above? Did you succeed in fixing your workflow?

Comment: I was able to fix the version of the unit test version, but I started over on the set-outputs. They are showing up as warnings, so at least they aren't failing.

Comment: @jessehouwing works an absolute charm thank you for saving me some time :)